# How to pre-populate the Facebook status message through an URL similar to pre-populating a tweet?

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

This question has been asked before on SO, but most of those questions were asked a long time ago.

Essentially, we want a simple way to pre-populate the Facebook status message through the URL much like you can with Twitter.

We're aware of the Facebook APIs, but are wondering if there is a more lightweight approach.

We don't need programmatically to post a message, but just provide some default text that the user can edit before sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the FB sharer - <s>though it's supposed to be deprecated for a year or so it still works just fine</s>. just add a link to a page or forward your user to this url (change the www.myDomain/path/ part):

Forward to:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?src=sp&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myDomain.com%2Fpath%2F
```

or add link like that:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?src=sp&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myDomain.com%2Fpath%2F">Share on FB</a>
```

be aware that all info that's presented for your page can be set via META tags which must be present on the page that was passed to the sharer.php. You canNOT change the title, image and description via some other variable

that's about as lightweight as it gets - hope it helps

**Update:** see http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags for a good tutorial on the meta tags

**Update 2014-01:** the API is no longer deprecated... lol

Comment: What meta tags can you use to change which fields? Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm not sure what the situation was when you wrote this answer but if you're saying that the "src" parameter can be used to pre-populate the text, then this seems to no longer be the case.

Comment: no I am not saying that. re-read my post please ;-) that was never possible AFAIK

Comment: The sharer.php facebook url is no longer deprecated as of right now. On their docs page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/), see the "Can I use the Share Dialog without using the Share Button?" question in the FAQ section.

Comment: This answer does not seem correct, it does not fill the message box, it just fills the url/link/preview/whatever that is called. Below's answer from covati should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 29):

That actually violates the FB TOS:

> Policy Violation:
> Pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo album captions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Facebook doesn't want you to tell users what to say.

Comment: it's a little silly i think, i don't see their argument. If someone chooses to engage in such an act they should be allowed.

Comment: It's to prevent people from running scams that require you to post some specific text. That type of activity turns FB into a mess of crappy wall posts. They are on a constant battle with game companies and contest apps that flood walls with useless posts. For those of us who aren't spammers, it's annoying, but it's their site - their rules.

Comment: i agree with you, i think i was a little frustrated when i found out i couldn't do that.

Comment: I agree with @covati, this is for the good of everyone. Also note that the terms do not prevent you from pre-filling the values when the user generated the content themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 'Message' property in either 'Feed dialog' or 'POST' method of GRAPH API.

As you dont want to use much of code, you may use the Feed dialog and you can give the text whatever you want to populate in the 'Message' property.

But remember you need the user_access_token for the message to be displayed.

See the following links for information

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: I'm not sure what the case was when this answer was written but the "message" property is now only supported in the POST method of the API, not the feed dialog.

Comment: In the first link, properties like 'caption' and 'description' are described. If you can't use meta tags for some reason, this seems to be a good idea.