# Facebook share with prefilled message

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share

I have a page with a text area and would like to use a facebook share api so that the message that is written by the user in this text area is automatically prefilled in the message section of facebook share dialog.
As I know, it is not forbidden by the policy of facebook (the case when the message was written by the user), but haven't found any examples in the docs.

```
<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea id="message" placeholder="Please leave a short message"></textarea>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://someurl.com/" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fsomeurl.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible by adding `&quote=yourmessagehere` at the end of URL.

For example:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://someurl.com&src=sdkpreparse&quote=yourmessagehere

Try it out! Thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like this works anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9741109/452587